# Auto refresh a Div without scrolling to the top of Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that refreshes a Div on my website every 20 seconds. The problem is, once it refreshes, it scrolls to the to of the Div. I want it to stay at the last position and not scroll to the top after a refresh. Could someone please look at this script and maybe point out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
var time = new Date().getTime();

var refreshTime = 20*1000;

$(document).bind("blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave change select submit keydown keypress keyup error hover change", function(e) {
    time = new Date().getTime(); 
});

var lastScrollPos = 0;

$('#feed1').on('scroll', function() {
    lastScrollPos = this.scrollTop;
});

function refresh() {

    if(new Date().getTime() - time >= refreshTime)

        $('#feed1').load(location.href="/dashboard" , function () {
            $(this).scrollTop(lastScrollPos);
        });

    else

        setTimeout(refresh, refreshTime);

}

setTimeout(refresh, refreshTime);
```

Comment: dude first of all What is Where? indent your code properly remove extra lines and provide js comments where ever necessary

Comment: I apologize, I'm in the very early learning stages.

Comment: What in the world is going on here? You do realize with all those bindings your time variable will be updated constantly, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you do `location.href="/dashboard"`, the browser will discard all the page's state (including scripting variables) and load "/dashboard" (assigning a value to `location.href` is identical to calling `location.assign("/dashboard")`).

The [jQuery load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) will probably not even require you to reposition the scroll offset, if you gave it chance to execute!

Try:

```
$('#feed1').load("/dashboard #feed1");
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems the HTTP request fired by jQuery's load mechanism is receiving a truncated response in your case (content-length: 0).

You would have to put the scroll position you want to keep into localStorage.  Try:

```
var time = new Date().getTime();

var refreshTime = 20*1000;

$(document).bind("blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave change select submit keydown keypress keyup error hover change", function(e) {
    time = new Date().getTime(); 
});

var previousScrollPos = localStorage.getItem("lastScrollPos");
if(previousScrollPos)
{
    $('#feed1').scrollTop(previousScrollPos);
    localStorage.removeItem("lastScrollPos");
}

function refresh() {

    if(new Date().getTime() - time >= refreshTime)
    {
        localStorage.setItem("lastScrollPos", $('#feed1').scrollTop());
        location.reload();
    }

}

setInterval(refresh, refreshTime);
```

I'm not 100% sure that you want to bind to the scroll event of #feed1 or just of body, I haven't seen your page.  If anybody clicks "load more" on the news feed, those additional items will be hidden again since you're reloading the page.  Not ideal at all.

Many users will hate having the page periodically reload, it's also an accessibility failure since this will interfere with screen reading software.  It might be a simpler idea to just put a refresh newsfeed icon on the page, which just reloads the whole page, when the user wants to (instead of periodically).

Comment: When I use `$('#feed1').load("/dashboard #feed1");`, it refreshes to a blank page, #feed1 disappears.

Comment: @sw0277, then it didn't find either "/dashboard" or it did not contain an element with an id of `feed1` perhaps feed1 is dynamically generated?  Dunno, I cannot see your website. It's all guesswork I'm afraid.

Comment: I believe it is dynamically generated. I have tried your suggestion before with the same results. The only way I could get it to actually reload just #feed1 (which is a news feed) is by using `location.href=`. That's why I was trying to figure out a way to get it to remember the scroll position, that would solve my issue.

Comment: @sw0277 Um, but why can't you just dynamically generate it again? Using the same technique used to dynamically generate it in the first place?

Comment: @sw0277: To remember the scroll position, you need to put it somewhere that will survive the page reloading, like localStorage.  But the jQuery complete callback will not fire if using location.href, location.assign, or any method of reloading the document.  Everything will be cancelled.

Comment: This is my situation. I'm running software named Oxwall [link](http://www.oxwall.org/index). It's social networking software, the newsfeed (#feed1) is a plugin. The newsfeed will not update automatically after someone posts something. I figured out that I could create a custom text/html widget with the code I posted here and put it on the same page as the newsfeed. By doing this the script will only run when your on that page just refreshing the newsfeed when there's no user activity. It works pretty good aside from the fact it scrolls back to the top of the newsfeed after a refresh.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid making changes to core files because after every update all changes are lost and have to be redone.

Comment: @sw0277: So what does the HTML you embed into #feed1 look like?

Comment: I don't embed any HTML. The custom text/HTML widgets that your able to create will accept java script as well. The script I posted here is the only thing that's in that custom text/HTML widget.

Comment: @sw0277 Hmm... *you* might not embed the HTML yourself, but the widget your using will have some embedded code to get it to appear on your page.  Do you have any links to any pages that contain this widget?

Comment: My sites not open to guests I can email you a test accounts log in details that has admin privileges. Or you can sign up and I will grant you admin privileges. https://torchzone.com

Comment: @sw0277 I'd rather not have the admin priviliges!  Just let me know which oxwall plugin you're using and I'll see what I can fnd out.

Comment: OK, I understand. It's just the standard newsfeed plugin that comes with oxwall. You can see it here [link](http://www.oxwall.org/store/item/43). I really appreciate this!

Comment: @sw0277 I can see from their demo page that if you use jQuery.load() to try to refresh the newsfeed, the response has a content-length of 0, which means the server/framework is configured to reject/deny XMLHTTPRequests.

Comment: Wow, thanks for getting back with me so fast! The script you posted works fine, I think that's going to be everyone's best option for now until someone were to actually build a plugin that can accomplish this. I see what you mean about the view more button, but at the same time it might not be so bad. If a few people were to be down the page a ways and all commenting on the same post, you get a notification that someone has commented on that post and are directly taken to that comment. I also have an "auto view more" plugin that removes the "view more button" and completely automates it.

Comment: I have not tried the "auto view more" plugin with this script but either way I would sacrafice that plugin to use this script if I have to. I plan on setting this script to fire off about 10 min after there's no user activity so hopefully that will help if anyone's using screen reading software. I am going to replace the script I originally posted on Oxwall's forum with the one you have provided me. Would it be OK if I give you and stackoverflow credit for this, when I post this on Oxwall's forum?

Comment: @sw0277 fine by me, but no need to credit me, I only edited your code to fit what you originally wanted to do.

Comment: And thanks for not giving me a hard time about my "poor coding skills". I'm definitely not an idiot, I have been a licensed electrician for 9 years now, just new to the coding world. Thanks again man, much respect!

Comment: You were right, I don't think this will be a decent solution to this issue. It works perfect in Firefox, Internet Explorer don't seem to remember the last scroll position and Google Chrome you can physically see the whole page refresh. When using Firefox it gives the illusion that only the news feed is updating. Thanks for all your help anyway man...

Comment: @sw0277 yeah the jQuery load function would have been the best compromise if it wasn't for Oxwall (or something else) returning empty responses.  I don't know much about Oxwall still, it just looks like the newsfeed plugin's API is lacking a reload() function.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use **feed1** div only for loading your dashboard contents and handle its position using style.

```
#feed1 {
height: 150px;
overflow: auto;
```

}

Add other data outside **feed1** div because **load** method will overwrite **feed1's** content.

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nmusmani/h9pu4o4u/) if you are looking for something similar otherwise you can modify this example so that other can understand your requirement/scenario.